# Folder Permissions for Assets, Cache, and temp

Tags: cache, error-message, permissions

I have set 755 permissions to these folders and they are owned by the PHP web user.

However, I'm still getting logs that say:

```
[error] [application] Could not delete the file /var/www/craft/storage/runtime/assets/sources/76.jpg because the file does not exist.



Tried to read the folder contents of /var/www/craft/storage/runtime/temp/, but could not.

Tried to read the folder contents of /var/www/craft/storage/runtime/cache/, but could not.
```

76.jpg does exist. And I don't know why it can't read those folders. Any ideas how to fix this??

Comment: What user:group is the web server running as and what user:group owns the files and folders?

Comment: My php runs with the www-data user. The files and groups are set to that user.

Comment: What happens if you load up Craft's `bootstrap.php` file in a script and do `IOHelper::deleteFile('/var/www/craft/storage/runtime/assets/sources/76.jpg');`

Comment: @BradBell I'm very new to Craft. I'm not sure what you are wanting me to do? Am I loading this in a template file or something?

Comment: Create a `test.php` and put it in your public HTML folder with these contents: https://gist.github.com/takobell/1a8c98d0ad69e2c99dc984b993bb7479 Then load up yourdomain.com/test.php in a browser and see what gets output to the screen.

Comment: It gives me a 500 error

Comment: You might need to adjust `$craft = require '../craft/app/bootstrap.php';` if your `craft` folder is not one level above web root.

Comment: My craft folder is 1 level above:
My craft/ and html/ directory are located in the www/ directory.

Comment: When I remove the 2 .. before the path. I get this output:
Warning: require(/craft/app/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/test.php on line 12

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/craft/app/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/test.php on line 12

Comment: Try the updated Gist: https://gist.github.com/takobell/1a8c98d0ad69e2c99dc984b993bb7479

Comment: It returned fail.

Comment: And did you get a new `Could not delete the file` message in your log files?

Comment: This morning I got "fail" twice. Then I logged into my craftcms and then re-ran the the script. It says "success" but in the log file it says: Could not delete the file /var/www/craft/storage/runtime/assets/sources/76.jpg because the file does not exist.

Comment: The file doesn't exist now... so I have no idea what was wrong... because we didn't change anything. Other than running that script.